# ¿Puedo poner un zoom predeterminado al navegador al cargar una página?

Tags: css, web, navegador-web

Como bien dice el titulo de la pregunta, me pregunto si podría definir el zoom que quiero que tenga el navegador al cargar mi pagina web. Eso me ahorraría mucho trabajo porque sino tendría que adaptarla con bootstrap dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agregar la propiedad `zoom` al `body` de tu página web.

Ejemplo:

```css
body{
  zoom: 30;
}
```

```html
<span>Hola<span>
```

También lo puedes realizar mediante porcentajes.

Ejemplo:

```css
body{
  zoom: 170%;
}
```

```html
<span>Hola<span>
```

Si en vez de usar CSS lo quisieras agregar mediante Javascript podrías usar:

```
document.body.style.zoom = "170%";
```

**RECOMENDACIÓN:** NO uses diferentes tipos de zoom para distintos tipos de pantallas. En su defecto, realiza tu página web responsive.

Que sea responsive no significa que el mismo contenido se vea en todo tipo de pantallas si no que, dependiendo de la pantalla, reordenes la distribución de los elementos en el layout. Incluso puedes ocultar los elementos que no sean relevantes para pantallas pequeñas (como por ejemplo imágenes de cabecera).

Hacer tu página `responsive` tendría que ser una prioridad antes de intentar realizar varios tipos de zoom dependiendo de cada pantalla, ya que puede ser muy molesto para el usuario final y que tu página no reciba la atención necesaria.

Comment: Bueno me hace el zoom correcto, lo malo esque me descoloca muchas cosas, pero gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @PictorGames Me alegro de que te haya sido de ayuda. Sin embargo, ¿puedo preguntar el porque quieres que el usuario tenga zoom? Yo lo dejaría al que tenga el usuario por defecto en el navegador.

Comment: Por lo general ésta regla css sirve, sin embargo no es un estándar y por ende, Firefox no la implementa. Inicialmente fue una regla implementada solo en IE. Respecto a que te descoloca, es porque muy seguramente estás usando unidades no relativas como píxeles. Para que escale correctamente debes usar unidades relativas como `rem` o `em`.

Comment: @guzgarcia Gracias por las aclaraciones. La verdad que no lo he probado en otros navegadores y, aunque sé que existe, no lo he usado nunca ya que pienso que es mejor dejar al usuario elegir el zoom que mejor le convenga.

Comment: @Error404 Simplemente es porque dependiendo de las pantallas, un usuario puede verlo de formas diferentes... lo malo es que es contradictorio, porque los usuario que tengan la pantalla mas grande lo veran mas pequeño... tendre que currarme mas la estructura HTML y utilizar `@media (max-width: 543px)` HAAA!!!! se me ha ocurrido una idea!! puedo marcar una `@media ()` con los px de las pantallas grandes y poner el zom predeterminado y otra con las pantallas medianas!!!!

Comment: @PictorGames Ahora mismo te pillo menos que al principio. Es decir, ¿lo que quieres hacer es que para patallas más pequeñas quepa todo el contenido y por eso quieres el uso del zoom?

Comment: mira, con el zoom 100% digamos que los elementos se solapan, pero al ponerlo al 70% se ve correctamente. Lo malo es que en las pantallas grandes, cuando esta al 100% se ve bien!!! Esto es porque yo he de trabajar sobre un codigo mal realizado (lo tipoco..)

Comment: @PictorGames Te recomiendo que no cambies el zoom dependiendo de la pantalla si no que redistribuyas tu layout según el tipo de pantalla. Es decir, habrá elementos que los tendrás que mover de sitio e incluso habrá elementos que será mejor ocultarlos para pantallas pequeñas. Sin embargo, si lo que haces es intentar que un usuario que en una pantalla de 1200px x 800px (es un ejemplo ya que yo no me sé las medidas de como van las pantallas) en una pantalla de 200px x 350px, haciendo un zoom del 30% va a ser muy molesto al usuario. Te recomiendo que redistribuyas antes que hacer zoom.

Comment: @PictorGames Además, los usuarios tendrán que volver a hacer zoom para ver el contenido lo cual puede ser muy molesto para ellos y que al final tu página no sea visitada. La redistribución de la que te he hablado antes es el principio básico de las páginas web responsive. Que quepa todo en una misma pantalla y, que si no cabe, lo reordenes o lo ocultes para que se vea correctamente.

Comment: sisi gracias @Error404